# Unable to detect iCreate

Tags: turtlebot, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I am in the process of setting up my newly-built Turtlebot and am having an issue with ROS detecting my Turtlebot that is connected to my computer via a USB to Serial adapter. Any help would be MUCH appreciated. I have not confirmed that the USB to Serial adapter works in any application, but its presence in "lsusb" assures me it is running.

I am using the same machine as both my Workstation AND Turtlebot laptop (for now): Thinkpad T410 Running Ubuntu 12.04 Precise, ros-fuerte installed.
For my network setup, I simply gave the same IP twice. I am now attempting to run this tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/TurtleBot%20Bringup) but I get grey buttons in the dashboard. My IP addresses are correct (Unless Turtlebot is absolutely incompatible without two separate machines), so I performed some of the tests mentioned in the Networking tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup).

The Turtlebot is charged, every cable (Kinect, iCreate via USB-Serial adapter) is plugged into my box, but I still receive the following output:

```
    ~$ lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 17ef:480f Lenovo Integrated Webcam [R5U877]
//This is the USB to Serial converter I'm using: 
    Bus 001 Device 007: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
    Bus 002 Device 018: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
    Bus 002 Device 019: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
    Bus 002 Device 020: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
    Bus 002 Device 021: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
    
    ~$ sudo service turtlebot start
    turtlebot start/running, process 19893
    
    ~$ rostopic echo /diagnostics
//Yadda Yadda laptop info, then:
    ---
    header: 
      seq: 49
      stamp: 
        secs: 1348390103
        nsecs: 269546031
      frame_id: ''
    status: 
      - 
        level: 2
        name: TurtleBot Node
        message: Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer. 
    
        hardware_id: ''
        values: []
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44407/unable-to-detect-icreate/) by [DGonz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2579/dgonz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-09-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2012-09-22**:
And also can you please post the exact lines you added to your ~/.bashrc file to mention the IPs ?

**Comment by [DGonz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2579/dgonz/) on 2012-09-23**:
Yes, the lines are : #source /etc/environment
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://*myIP*:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=*myIP*
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://*myIP*:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=*myIP*

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-09-24**:
Ca you see the ports in /dev using ls -l?  Do you have permissions to access the port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try plugging the Create cable to a different port on your laptop other than the one it is plugged into now. I had the same problem, I inserted it into another port and it worked for me. Sometimes problems come with the laptop ports as well.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2012-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0